# Cgywin error in Win10 encountered while running jigsaw

Tags: php, java-platform-module-system

Trying to run tailwindcss docs it uses jigsaw and I'm running win10 but I get  We are in Cgywin using Windows php, so the path must be translated

when i type this is in my command :

```
$ php vendor/bin/jigsaw serve
```

I get this

```
dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../tightenco/jigsaw" && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ] && [[ $(which php) == $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/* ]]; then
   # We are in Cgywin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
   dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
fi

"${dir}/jigsaw" "$@"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post so that what's code is formatted as code, and what's normal text is formatted as normal text?

Comment: You just see that ? what I typed ? ? @domdambrogia

Comment: You're running PHP on a wrapper script generated by Composer for Cygwin environments on Windows. Because the file doesn't contain PHP interpreter blocks, the PHP runtime just echos the contents. Try invoking the script directly: `vendor/bin/jigsaw serve`

Comment: $ vendor/bin/jigsaw serve
'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I get this buddy @CyRossignol

Comment: @d3cypher I thought you were using a POSIX shell because you prefixed the command with a `$` in your question. The error message in your comment suggests that you're actually executing it with the Windows command prompt. Check *vendor/bin/* for a file named *jigsaw.bat*. If it exists you can invoke the batch file instead: `vendor\bin\jigsaw.bat serve`

Comment: i use cmder it uses lambda

Comment: is there any fix  ?